# Contacting a specific user on this site

Tags: discussion, chat, etiquette

I want to ask somebody a specific question, but I'm new here and I don't know the proper protocol.  Can I ask a question directly to a specific person?  If not in a private forum, does Stack Exchange allow generic questions/answers that may/may not be of interest to anyone else?  Questions such as, "Do you have a reference for your answer?", "Is this your profession?", or "How long have you been in this industry?"  Those types of questions.

Comment: If you specifically want someone to add references to an answer, you can post a comment on that answer.

Comment: Dan Hulme, after-the-fact, I realized "What is your reference?" was a bad example, because it's a pertinent question.  I appreciate your response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions of this nature would be generally off-topic for the main site.

For contacting a specific user you can see if they publish contact information on their profile, or check [in the site's chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/the-hangar) (many of us hang out there).

Comment: voretaq7, I now see where others post their contact information--thanks for the information!